# featureLayer.applyEdits saves POINT EMPTY in esri javascript API

Tags: javascript, esri

esri javascript API featureLayer.applyEdits  some time works and most of time saves POINT EMPTY in Geometry and set rest of attributes with Null value
here is the code

```
 featureLayer.applyEdits(drawnItems, null, null, function (add, update, del) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(drawnItems[0].attributes));
                ContaminantLayer.refresh();
                if(add[0].success===true)
                {
                  console.log("Success");
                }
             else {
                    toastr.error("Error occured ");
                }
            }, function (error) {
                toastr.error("Error occured ");

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I need to use Simplify() before saving the Geometry

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#simplify